# AndEngine. LinearLayout for AnimatedSprites

Tags: android, andengine

I'm novice in AndEngine. I make a simple game. I need something like LinearLayout with horizontal orientation. Items for it - AnimatedSprites. What should I use for this?
Now I use for it SpriteGroup and align childs by pixels. Maybe there is another way?